# How set Sound and Vibration for Notification in Oreo 8.0?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

I saw a youtube tutorial for creating notifications in Android 8, the only thing I don't understand is how to make notification sounds and vibrate.

Here is the code from the tutorial, which I added with the channel. second, channel.enable vibration, .setvibrate and setSound.

Helperclass for Channels:

```
public class App extends Application {
public static final String CHANNEL_1_ID = "channel1";
public static final String CHANNEL_2_ID = "channel2";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    createNotificationChannels();
}

private void createNotificationChannels() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel1 = new NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_1_ID,
                "Channel 1",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        );
        channel1.setDescription("This is Channel 1");
        channel1.setSound(null, null);
        channel1.setLockscreenVisibility(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        channel1.enableVibration(true);

        NotificationChannel channel2 = new NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_2_ID,
                "Channel 2",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
        );
        channel2.setDescription("This is Channel 2");
        channel2.setSound(null, null);
        channel2.setLockscreenVisibility(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        channel2.enableVibration(true);

        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel1);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel2);
    }
}
```

}

Mainactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager;
private EditText editTextTitle;
private EditText editTextMessage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

    editTextTitle = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_title);
    editTextMessage = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_message);
}

public void sendOnChannel1(View v) {
    String title = editTextTitle.getText().toString();
    String message = editTextMessage.getText().toString();

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_1_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_one)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
            .setVibrate(new long[] {2000})
            .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
            .build();

    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}

public void sendOnChannel2(View v) {
    String title = editTextTitle.getText().toString();
    String message = editTextMessage.getText().toString();

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_2_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_two)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setVibrate(new long[] {2000})
            .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
            .build();

    notificationManager.notify(2, notification);
 }
```

}

In the manifest, I added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

I can create Notifications on button click but without sound and vibration.
Can someone explain to me how this works in Android 8

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `VibrationPattern` to your `NotificationChannel`

Try this

```
private void createNotificationChannels() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel1 = new NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_1_ID,
                "Channel 1",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        );
        channel1.setDescription("This is Channel 1");
        channel1.setSound(null, null);
        channel1.setLockscreenVisibility(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        channel1.setVibrationPattern(new long[] {2000});
        channel1.enableVibration(true);

        NotificationChannel channel2 = new NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_2_ID,
                "Channel 2",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
        );
        channel2.setDescription("This is Channel 2");
        channel2.setSound(null, null);
        channel2.setLockscreenVisibility(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        channel2.setVibrationPattern(new long[] {2000});
        channel2.enableVibration(true);

        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel1);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this but still not working, installed the app on my smartphone and smartwatch, i get the notifications but no vibration or sound.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the lack of vibration: **Your Vibration Pattern is only a single Integer.**

```
 .setVibrate(new long[] {2000})
```

the pattern spec for the vibrator is `{offtime, ontime, offtime, ontime, offtime, ...}`.

Yes - for some odd reason, `offtime` comes *first*, so in your pattern, all you have specified is **2000ms of silence**. So even if the pattern was played correctly, you wouldn't know!

Set your pattern to be at least two integers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
NotificationChannel NCH1 = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_1,"channel1", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
```